# Dojo - OnDemandGrid - Pb on rendered

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dojo

I use the CustiomGrid

```
var CustomGrid = declare([ OnDemandeGrid, Keyboard, Selection ]);
```

and i use 4 Grid on my page.

The first is correctly rendered :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzRhh.png)

the others aren't rendered correctly :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2XsG.png)

I use Bootstraps Tabs to display Grid. Only when hidden, grid aren't rendered correctly.

Any Idea ?

Thanks

Cyril

Comment: adding some code will be better?

Comment: yes, the code is always better to help you...

Comment: I found the problem : Before, the "startup" of the grid was called when Grid were hidden.

Comment: Now, startup of the grid is called on this event : ('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) [...]